# Unity suddenly fails to create class when I added an interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

In the process of decoupling some code and I extracted an interface for one of our classes, and mapped it using Unity like so

```
Container.RegisterType<IUserAuthorizationBC, UserAuthorizationBC>(
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>());
```

As you can see the class is UserAuthorizationBC and the interface is of course IUserAuthorizationBC. Once i did this I began to get an error in a class that I thought would not have mattered. The ctor for the class that now gives an error is as follows

```
public RoleAuthorizationService(IDataContractFactory factory,
    UserAuthorizationBC businessProcessor)
        : base(factory, businessProcessor)
{
    _authBC = businessProcessor;
}
```

As you can see I haven't refactored it yet, I haven't even touched it, it was set up to get a concrete instance of UserAuthorizationBC and whoever created it is also injecting an IDataContractFactory which I did find mapped in our code base as you can see in following code snippet.

```
Container.RegisterType<IDataContractFactory, DefaultDataContractFactory>(
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>());
```

I get an error from unity as follows

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "HumanArc.Compass.Shared.Interfaces.Service.IRoleAuthorizationService",
>   name = "(none)".
>       Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest
>   interceptionRequest,
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[]
>   policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container).
>       Exception is: ArgumentException - Type passed must be an interface.

Now if I go comment out my mapping for IUserAuthorizationBC it will work fine again. I have no idea why.

actually I don't know why it ever works because if you look at the DefaultDataContractFactory it uses all generics which I would assume would always fail to resolve as at the time the unity doesn't know the type of T - see the class below.

```
public class DefaultDataContractFactory : IDataContractFactory
{
    public DefaultDataContractFactory();

    public virtual T Create<T>();
    public virtual object Create(Type type);
    public virtual Example<T> CreateExample<T>();
    protected Type CreateFactoryType(Type instanceType);
}
```

So to sum things up there are two questions.

1. How does it even work in the first place before I added an interface for the IUserAuthorizationBC class and then added the mapping for unity - I would think that the IDataContractFactory would always blow it up.
2. Since it does work if I comment out the container mapping for IUserAuthorizationBC why does it stop working when I uncomment it - I would have thought it wouldn't make a bit of difference as this particular class always has been injected with a concrete instance of the UserAuthorizationBC

I thought I understood dependency injection fairly well - especially with unity but I am clearly missing the boat here.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to make this a comment, but it's too long.  Maybe your `Unity` container is configured for convention-based registrations, so your explicit registration is confusing matters.  The `IDataContractFactory/DefaultDataContractFactory` pair needs to be explicity registered because the names don't follow the prescribed convention.

See if you have something like this in your code:

```
// This will register all types with a ISample/Sample naming convention 
            container.RegisterTypes(
                AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                WithName.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Prerequisite

Take a look at [Interception using Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx).  It looks like you are using interception with policy injection.  Two conditions need to be met in order for a method to be intercepted.  The policy needs to match on the method / type.  And the type needs to opt-in to interception in the Unity registration by selecting an interceptor (InterfaceInterceptor, VirtualMethodInterceptor, or TransparentProxyInterceptor).

### Answers

1. Commenting out that registration effectively opted-out that type from using interception.
2. You opted-in to interception but you told Unity to use *interface* interception.  You are not resolving an interface, so it doesn't know how to generate a proxy for interception.

### Possible solutions

- Leave the registration as-is with the InterfaceInterceptor and update all constructors to use your new interface instead of the concrete type.
- Change your new IUserAuthorizationBC registration to use VirtualMethodInterceptor and update any methods you want to be able to be intercepted to be virtual.
- Change your new IUserAuthorizationBC registration to not specify an interceptor to effectively opt-out of interception.